# browse local files and display in text field

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html

I have the below requirement. I want to browse the local files and display the location in the corresponding text field. The user can specify the file location directly by clicking in text box or he can choose the location by clicking on browse button and display location in text box. Any help is appreciated. Attached the image.

[image]

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service and asking for examples is off topic. Perhaps you should make a start and show your work if you encounter a specific problem.